# The maximum report processing jobs limit crystal report ,this is due to my code mistake?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am using Microsoft crystal report developer version using visual studio 2012.Before my report is working fine but when i deploy my report in production then after that I am getting  error the maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached in crystal report and also inside c->windows->temp folder .rpt file is not deleting.How can i delete this in temp folder.Is there any mistake in my code.I am using following code.How can i get rid of this error.I also read various forums but i did not find the solution

```
public partial class myClass : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/path/mainrep.rpt"));
                    crystalReport.SetDataSource(dtblstdtmtbl);
int exportFormatFlags = (int)(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat);
                    cviewer.AllowedExportFormats = exportFormatFlags;
                    cviewer.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
                    cviewer.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
                    cviewer.HasToggleParameterPanelButton = false;
                    cviewer.DisplayGroupTree = false;
                    cviewer.EnableDrillDown = false;

                    cviewer.ReportSource = crystalReport;
   }




protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseReports(crystalReport); 
            crystalReport.Close();
            crystalReport.Dispose();
            cviewer.Dispose();
            crystalReport = null;
            cviewer = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }//end page unload 


        private void CloseReports(ReportDocument reportDocument)
        {
            Sections sections = reportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections;
            foreach (Section section in sections)
            {
                ReportObjects reportObjects = section.ReportObjects;
                foreach (ReportObject reportObject in reportObjects)
                {
                    if (reportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                    {
                        SubreportObject subreportObject = (SubreportObject)reportObject;
                        ReportDocument subReportDocument = subreportObject.OpenSubreport(subreportObject.SubreportName);
                        subReportDocument.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            reportDocument.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: how are you deploying in production?

Comment: i build the project and deployed

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error in Crystal Report when it give this following message.

"The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached."

It actually means that the Crystal Report print job limit has been reached and you should handle this problem by increasing the job limit in the registry. The basic reason for this problem is Garbage Collector (GC) cannot clear the reference of report documents in their collection process its only a clear report viewer.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CRYSTAL DECISIONS\10.0\REPORT APPLICATION SERVER\SERVER\PrintJobLimit